# How are asymptotic p-values calculated in Hmisc: rcorr?

Tags: r, correlation, p-value, pearson-correlation, hmisc

I am using the rcorr function within the Hmisc package in R to develop Pearson correlation coefficients and corresponding p-values when analyzing the correlation of several fishery landings time series. The data isn't really important here but what I would like to know is: how are the p-values calculated for this? It states that the asymptotic P-values are approximated by using the t or F distributions but I am wondering if someone could help me find some more information on this or an equation that describes how exactly these values are calculated.

Comment: Perhaps the [source code](https://github.com/harrelfe/Hmisc/blob/master/R/rcorr.s#L28) could assist you? Otherwise there may be information in the references from the documentation for that method:  References
_Hollander M. and Wolfe D.A. (1973). Nonparametric Statistical Methods. New York: Wiley._
_Press WH, Flannery BP, Teukolsky SA, Vetterling, WT (1988): Numerical Recipes in C. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press._

Comment: https://www.danielsoper.com/statcalc/formulas.aspx?id=61 https://courses.lumenlearning.com/introstats1/chapter/testing-the-significance-of-the-correlation-coefficient/